# XAMPP And file_get_contents("https://...")

Tags: php, xampp

I've tried running the next code on xampp :

```
$url2="https://....";
$content=file_get_contents($url2);
```

and that's the error I've got :

```
Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in C:\xampp\htdocs\whoTalk\sys\user.php on line 38
```

What do I have to do in order to be able to get contents of a url which a https:// wrapper?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your php.ini search for the following:

`extension=php_openssl.dll`

If it is there and commented, uncomment it. If it is not there, add it :-)

Comment: I've added this setting but still get this error ... do I have to refresh the xampp settings somehow ?

Comment: You'll need to restart Apache

Answer (score 1):

in WAMP I added

```
allow_url_include = On
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
```

to all 3 php.ini files I could find, namely

```
\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.ini
\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\phpForApache.ini
\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini
```

I don't know which specific settings in which .ini file is actually needed, but https is accepted now....

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have the OpenSSL extension for PHP enabled in XAMPP to grab anything from a secure server.